# How do I keep the angle of a body in pybox2d between -pi and pi?

Tags: python, box2d, physics

In the [pybox2d manual](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/wiki/manual) it states the following:

> pybox2d uses radians for angles. The body rotation is stored in
>   radians and may grow unbounded. Consider normalizing the angle of your
>   bodies if the magnitude of the angle becomes too large (use
>   b2Body.SetAngle).

However, when I try to implement something to 'normalize' the angle I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'b2Body' object has no attribute 'SetAngle'
```

Code snippet:

```
def update_outputs(self):

    # This is necessary to prevent the angle
    # from getting too large or small
    self.body.SetAngle(self.body.angle % 2*pi)
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++? Is it related to this language?

Comment: pybox2d is actually a binding of a C++ library called Box2D.

Comment: I'm using pybox2d version 2.3.1 but the manual for 2.1.0 so I wonder if it is out of date.

Comment: *"pybox2d is actually a binding of a C++ library called Box2D."* That's great, but do you have a question about C++ code? Is knowledge about C++ helpful here? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: Okay sorry about that.  I'll remove the C++ tag.  Regards.

Comment: PS: It would be great if someone could create a pybox2d tag (I am not authorized to create new tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the library has been pythonized since those docs were written.  angle is a property of Body:

```
@angle.setter
def angle(self, angle):
    self._xf.angle=angle
    self._transform_updated()
```

You should be able to simply set it with something like:

```
def update_outputs(self):

    # This is necessary to prevent the angle
    # from getting too large or small
    self.body.angle %= 2*pi
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks! (I tried `self.body.angle = self.body.angle % 2*pi` but in so doing fell for the operator precedence trap...).