# Function expects a float but is given a property

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, windows-10, box2d

I’m using Pybox2d and I want to get the angle of a body. I’ve found very little literature regarding the Python version of Box2d except for the manual which is from 2011. I’ve gotten by through following with JavaScript and C++ Box2d tutorials but it seems they part ways with the Python version on a few things.

Every resource I could find, including the 2011 manual, said to just do `body.GetAngle()` but it doesn’t seem like that method is available to me. I tried `body.angle` but It causes an error because I’m expecting it to return a float and it returns a property instead. I opened up the Box2d.py file in Pycharm and it looks like the function exists but it has leading double underscores and is passed in as the getter argument of `angle = property(__GetAngle(), __SetAngle())`

I couldn’t cast it to a float, which was the only trick I could come up with. How do I simply get the angle of a body?

Comment: Pybox2d uses radians for angles. The body rotation is stored in radians and may grow unbounded. Consider normalizing the angle of your bodies if the magnitude of the angle becomes too large (use b2Body.SetAngle).

Comment: It gave me an Attribute Error: ‘b2Body’ object has no attribute ‘SetAngle’. It looks like the get and set angle methods both have the double underscore prefix and I don’t seem to have access to them. The thing I can actually get my hands on is the angle property which has the getter and setter as arguments. The problems is that when I try to do something like math.sin(self.body.angle) I get an error because the self.body.angle returns a property instead of the SupportsFloat that math.sin() is expecting

Comment: After more experimentation I’ve solved it. I have to set a local variable angle = self.body.angle and then pass it in math.sin(angle) and it works. In hindsight this was an obvious thing to try

Comment: After further further experimentation this solution, in fact, does not work. Sigh.

Comment: You might try the Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41419503/how-do-i-keep-the-angle-of-a-body-in-pybox2d-between-pi-and-pi).